# how to update languages manually

Tags: kubuntu, language-support

I have this message on kubuntu, but i want to resolve this manually in case this is some type of trojan.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install the missing packages and make that message go away, run this command:

```
sudo apt install $(check-language-support)
```